# Using multithreading in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

Trying to use multithreading in calculating of the integral. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

I think, that calculating the integral from 0 to 20000 is slower(about time) than I'd divide it on (0-10000) to (10000-2000). That's why I wanted to check the time of realization a function.

At the first, I tried to calculate from 0 to 20000 and I got the defining time of realization of a function.

At the second, I was trying to divide it on segments and got the defining time of realization of functions but if I'd sum the times, and I'd get bigger time that it was before. Why?

In my opinion, I'm wrong with the using multithreading. Can you help me with that?

*But the second problem is that I get wrong resulsts with the calculating < but it happens, when I try to calculate big numbers, like 0-10000, for example. But as for 0-3, it's okay.Is my method of calculating mistaken? But why is it okay with small numbers (like:0-3)?

Here is my code, please help me to figure out..

**The class**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <mutex>
#define N 10000

class Integral
{
private:
    std::mutex mtx;
    double S, x, h;
public:
    Integral() :S(0),x(0), h(0) {}
    double givingFunction(int x);
    void solvingFunction(double a, double b);
};
```

**Integral.cpp**

```
#include "Integral.h"
#include <chrono> 

double Integral::givingFunction(int x)
{
    double f;
    f = x+x;
    return f;
}
void Integral::solvingFunction(double a, double b)
{
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    mtx.lock();

    /*std::cout << "Enter a: ";
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << "Enter b: ";
    std::cin >> b;*/
    //a = 3;
    //b = 0;


    std::cout <<std::endl;

    h = (b - a) / N;

    x = a + h;
    while (x<b)
    {
        S = S + 4 * givingFunction(x);
        x = x + h;
        if (x >= b)
            break;
        S = S + 2 * givingFunction(x);
        x = x + h;
    }

    S = (h / 3)*(S + givingFunction(a) + givingFunction(b));
    std::cout << "Result:" << S <<std::endl;

    mtx.unlock();
    auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed = finish - start;
    std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << elapsed.count() << " s\n";

}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Integral.h"
#include <thread>
int main()
{

    Integral w; 
    std::thread Solve(&Integral::solvingFunction,&w,0.,1000.);
    std::thread Solve1(&Integral::solvingFunction,&w, 1000., 20000.);

    Solve.join();
    Solve1.join();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you are not running your threads in parallel. You are locking in the first thread, and then the 2nd thread is waiting for the first to finish (blocked in the mutex lock function) and only then it starts.

Comment: @Sil            So is my mistake not correct using `mutex`?

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong in your program... 1. there is no point in shareing the S, x and h variables. 2. if you want to share them you cannot run the threads in parallel because they are used in the hot loop inside each thread (there is so much more to be said on this subject) 3. you do realize that you are dividing from 0 to 1.000 and then 1.000 to 20.000?

Comment: @Sil           Thank you for hints. I'll try to fix it.

Comment: No problem, I'm sorry I don't have time to explain some more. but what you can do is leave the progam as it is but use a locally declared sum in each function and update that local sum in the while loop and only at the end of the thread use the mutex to update the S variable. Hope this helps

Comment: I think you need to calculate your integral over the two separate intervals independently (using only local variables) and combine the results at the end of each thread. Only lock the *mutex* to add the local results to the class member variable total when each thread ends.

Comment: @Sil           Sure, this will help! I'll do this.Thanks one more time!

Comment: Even then it still may not run faster because `20000` seems rather small for modern processors and the overhead of lauching a thread may outweigh the benefit.

Comment: exacty... this is in the "there is so much more to say about this" section...

Comment: @Galik          Can you help with the realization, please? I haven't understood about  `Only lock the mutex to add the local results` and `declared sum in each function`. If you can? please..

Comment: Remember, a thread has creation and maintenance overhead.  You'll need to determine if the overhead execution time is smaller or larger than the time spent in the thread.  Also, the OS has to schedule the threads.  There may not be extra cores to run your threads, so it will run all the threads (including the main thread), on the same core.  Most OS have other tasks running besides your program than they require CPU resources as well as memory resources (especially the data bus).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews  Oh, yes,  thatnk you for the explanation.Now I got about time sources.